# How to call a Javascript function within page load method?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using a currency converter Web Service and I have written a Javascript to show the result on button click. I want the javascript to fire on page load. I tried doing this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, this.GetType(), "Javascript", "function(data);", true);
}
```

But still the function does not fire. 
This is the JS i am using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnConvert').click(function () {
            var amount = $('#txtAmount').val();
            var from = $('#ddlfrom').val();
            var to = $('#ddlto').val();
            $.ajax({ type: "POST",
                url: "WebService.asmx/CurrencyConversion",
                data: "{amount:" + amount + ",fromCurrency:'" + from + "',toCurrency:'" + to + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var dot = data.d.indexOf(".");
                    var eg = data.d.substring(0, dot + 2);
                    var eg1 =data.d.substring(11, 50);
                                        $('#currency_converter_result').html(eg + eg1);
              }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want the click event to fire on load.  You don't need the pageload part.  Just add `click()` to the binding.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnConvert').click(function () {
            var amount = $('#txtAmount').val();
            var from = $('#ddlfrom').val();
            var to = $('#ddlto').val();
            $.ajax({ type: "POST",
                url: "WebService.asmx/CurrencyConversion",
                data: "{amount:" + amount + ",fromCurrency:'" + from + "',toCurrency:'" + to + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var dot = data.d.indexOf(".");
                    var eg = data.d.substring(0, dot + 2);
                    var eg1 =data.d.substring(11, 50);
                                        $('#currency_converter_result').html(eg + eg1);
              }
            });
        }).click();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I was new to javascript, I did not knew that was so easy.Thanks a lot sir.

Comment: It's one of those "tricks" that I learned on this site.  Just passing along the knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

It should work but you're sending the JS `function();` which means totally nothing.

`$(function(){});` is just an alias for `$(document).ready(function(){});`

[source](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: well yes, what i said.

Comment: $(function(data){}) i forgot to mention data as an argument i am using. I made an edit !

Comment: It doesn't change anything, you're not calling any function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything in code behind

`$(function () {
});`

is equivalent of

`$( document ).ready(function() {  });`

So anything within `$(function() { });` will be called automatically when page is loaded

Answer (score 0):

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#btnConvert').click(function () {
// paste the other code
```

});});

you don't need to use any js calling from code behind